# ubuntu is freezing very much, there is a need to fix this!

Tags: nvidia, 20.10, bug-reporting, debugging

ubuntu is a great operating system and it has everything which we want for our use. but it has a problem, it is freezing very much. everything just stops, no keyboard keys work and not the mouse and cursor works. we use nvidia GPU, gt 730, and we have proper driver of it and we have also installed the graphics driver ppa, to be up to date, but then also this happens.

it doesn't happen everyday, but at any random time. we are using ubuntu 20.10 and its stable, so it shouldn't happen like this. i hope this gets fixed in future ubuntu updates. and we also have a 16gb of RAM stick but still it happens

Comment: There is no actual question here or a clear indication of a problem. This is a question and answer site state a clear question and maybe someone can be of help.

Comment: After a "sudden shutdown", and reboot, the terminal  command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's log's. If there is no hint there, suspect power/ overheating.

Comment: System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV.

Comment: All of the above and adding that maybe your memory sticks are faulty. Random freezes is more likely to be faulty memory than anything else.

Comment: i have 16GB RAM and i don't do any heavy work, but still this problem is there!